# How to convert EmberJS model back to the regular JS array?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In order to use a JS function I must pass an array with my songs (objects) to it. The thing is - the songs are stored in EmberJS models. How do I convert back to regular JS arrays from EmberJS models?

```
App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Song.FIXTURES = [{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Foo"
}, {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Bar"
}];
```

So the problem is that:

```
App.Song.all() !== [{id: 1, name: "Foo"}, {id: 2, "name": "Bar"}];
```

Comment: you have a typo when closing the FIXTURES array, the end bracket is missing `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work

```
 App.Song.all().toArray()
```

Comment: Already tried this, but, unfortunately this doesn’t work. Returns: `[isEnumerable: true, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function…]`. So this - `App.Song.all().toArray() === App.Song.FIXTURES` returns `false`. Only when I navigate away from this (song) page and navigate back to it for the 2nd time I get the expected, needed results. So I quess that now the question is - how do I get that data the 1st time I open up the song page?

Comment: maybe your songs are not completly loaded. try App.Song.all().then(function(songs){songs.toArray()})

Comment: Aparently this is a bug. Your example with `then()` should have worked. Implemented the fix and it works. Thanks! https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735